# I am trying to add a png image but it is not loading?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

[image: This is my image directory]

I am trying to make an app where in by pressing the flat Button the image should change

This is my Code .Here the image is not able to load .It is throwing some exception despite my

pubspec.yaml file being correct.Can someone help me out.I am trying to use a random function inside my flat button to update my images on pressed.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:math';
    void main() {
      runApp(Magic());
    }
    class Magic extends StatefulWidget {
      const Magic({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _MagicState createState() => _MagicState();
    }
    
    class _MagicState extends State<Magic> {
      var i=1;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home:Scaffold(
            backgroundColor:Colors.blue,
            appBar: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title:Text( 'Ask Me Anything',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
              ),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
            ),
            body: Container(
              child:FlatButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   setState(() {
                     i = Random().nextInt(5)+1;
                   });
                 },
                child:Image(
                image:AssetImage('images/dice$i.png'),
                )
              ),
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

My Pubspec.yaml file

```
 name: magicball
    description: A new Flutter project.
    
    # The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
    # pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
    
    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
    
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    
    
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
    
    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
    
      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true
    
      assets:
        - images/ball1.png
        - images/ball2.png
        - images/ball3.png
        - images/ball4.png
        - images/ball5.png
        - images/dice1.png
        - images/dice2.png
        - images/dice3.png
        - images/dice4.png
        - images/dice5.png
        - images/dice6.png
    
      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
    
      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
    
      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

This is the error

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/dice4.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/dice4.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#70fe4(), name: "images/dice4.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: please share your project structure for images directory.

Comment: Done !!..Pls check it now!

Comment: Seems all is right. Try flutter clean, then pub get and start app again

Answer (score 1):

create an `assets` folder and put the `images` folder there.
and change the path to `- assets/images/ball1.png`. or you can just put the reference of the folder there.